# How can I get my ScrollViewer to scroll the view area?

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, scrollviewer

I have a **Grid** inside a **ScrollViewer** inside a **Border** inside a **StackPanel** inside a **Window**.

The ScrollViewer puts a **scrollbar** on the right, but it is **not scrollable**.

**How can I get the ScrollViewer to make its contents scrollable?**

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1bl34e1.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1bl34e1.png)

```
<Window x:Class="TestScroll234343.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="150" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
    <!--<StackPanel Height="150"> doesn't work either-->
        <Border>
            <ScrollViewer>            
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row0"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row1"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row2"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row3"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row4"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row5"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row6"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row7"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row8"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row9"/>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set the height of the `ScrollViewer`.

If you don't, the `Border` ask the `ScrollViewer` what height do it want and the `ScrollViewer` asks the `Border` what height should it be.

Other options:

- Change the `StackPanel` for a `DockPanel` (it does not grow more than the `Window`)
- Set the height of the `StackPanel` and bind to it in the `ScrollViewer`

Code:

```
 <StackPanel Height="140">
    <Border>
        <ScrollViewer Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                    AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=Height}">
```

Comment: It works if I set the height of the ScrollViewer or the Border, but not the StackPanel or the Window. Is there anyway to tell the ScrollViewer to become the height of the control it is in?

Comment: +1, but I also noticed one problem. In my case, I surround ScrollView with ListBox, now the mouse scroll can only scroll along the scroll bar not inside the ListBox. Guess ListBox doesn't relate to the ScrollView. How to allow it scroll on the content as well? (In my original design, I didn't specify the ScrollViewer)